# HTTP Caching with Retrofit 2.0.x

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp

I'm trying to cache some responses in my app using Retrofit 2.0, but I'm missing something.

I installed a caching file as follows:

```
private static File httpCacheDir;
private static Cache cache;
try {
    httpCacheDir = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "http");
    httpCacheDir.setReadable(true);
    long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
    HttpResponseCache.install(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
    cache = new Cache(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
    Log.i("HTTP Caching", "HTTP response cache installation success");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.i("HTTP Caching", "HTTP response cache installation failed:" + e);
}

public static Cache getCache() {
        return cache;
    }
```

which creates a file in `/data/user/0/<PackageNmae>/cache/http`
, then prepared a network interceptor as follows:

```
public class CachingControlInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        // Add Cache Control only for GET methods
        if (request.method().equals("GET")) {
            if (ConnectivityUtil.checkConnectivity(getContext())) {
                // 1 day
                request.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached")
                    .build();
            } else {
                // 4 weeks stale
                request.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-stale=2419200")
                    .build();
            }
        }

        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
            .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=86400")
            .build();
    }
}
```

my `Retrofit` and `OkHttpClient` instance:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setCache(getCache());
client.interceptors().add(new MainInterceptor());
client.interceptors().add(new LoggingInceptor());
client.networkInterceptors().add(new CachingControlInterceptor());
Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(client)
        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();

productsService = restAdapter.create(ProductsService.class);
```

where `ProductsService.class` contains:

```
@Headers("Cache-Control: max-age=86400")
@GET("categories/")
Call<PagedResponse<Category>> listCategories();
```

and

```
Call<PagedResponse<Category>> call = getRestClient().getProductsService().listCategories();
call.enqueue(new GenericCallback<PagedResponse<Category>>() {
      // whatever 
      // GenericCallback<T> implements Callback<T>
   }
});
```

The question here is: How to make it access cached responses when device being offline?

Header of backend response are:

```
Allow → GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Cache-Control → max-age=86400, must-revalidate
Connection → keep-alive
Content-Encoding → gzip
Content-Language → en
Content-Type → application/json; charset=utf-8
Date → Thu, 17 Dec 2015 09:42:49 GMT
Server → nginx
Transfer-Encoding → chunked
Vary → Accept-Encoding, Cookie, Accept-Language
X-Frame-Options → SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options → nosniff
x-xss-protection → 1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally I get the answer.

Network Interceptor should be as follow:

```
public class CachingControlInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        // Add Cache Control only for GET methods
        if (request.method().equals("GET")) {
            if (ConnectivityUtil.checkConnectivity(YaootaApplication.getContext())) {
                // 1 day
               request = request.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached")
                        .build();
            } else {
                // 4 weeks stale
               request = request.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-stale=2419200")
                        .build();
            }
        }

        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(request);
        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
            .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=600")
            .build();
    }
}
```

then installing cache file is that simple

```
long SIZE_OF_CACHE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
Cache cache = new Cache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "http"), SIZE_OF_CACHE);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.cache(cache);
client.networkInterceptors().add(new CachingControlInterceptor());
```

Comment: okhttp3.OkHttpClient's setCache method is not available
client.setCache(cache);

Comment: OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(cache).networkInterceptor(new CachingControlInterceptor()).build();

Comment: @Amr Barakat I want to implement caching for Post method also, is it possible? how?

Answer (score 8):

In your `CachingControlInterceptor`, you create new requests, but never actually use them.  You call `newBuilder` and ignore the result, so the header modification is never actually sent any where.  Try assigning those values to `request` and then instead of calling `proceed` on `chain.request()` call it on `request`.

```
public class CachingControlInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        // Add Cache Control only for GET methods
        if (request.method().equals("GET")) {
            if (ConnectivityUtil.checkConnectivity(getContext())) {
                // 1 day
                request = request.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached")
                    .build();
            } else {
                // 4 weeks stale
                request = request.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-stale=2419200")
                    .build();
            }
        }

        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(request);
        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
            .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=600")
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what the last part does?
return originalResponse.newBuilder()
            .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=600")
            .build();

Comment: I thought that if you add a header `("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached")`, it will retrieve it only if cached. Otherwise, it won't even bother making a network request.

Comment: @iagreen is it possible with "Post" method?

Answer (score 4):

you can also try:

```
public class CachingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        request = new Request.Builder()
                .cacheControl(new CacheControl.Builder()
                        .maxAge(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                        .minFresh(4, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                        .maxStale(8, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                        .build())
                .url(request.url())
                .build();


        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered the solution that worked for me in Retrofit 2.x and OkHttp 3.x

I had to implement **two Interceptors**, one of them is responsible to rewrite the **Request headers** and the other to rewrite the **Response headers**.

1. First, make sure you delete any old cache. (root explorer /data/data/com.yourapp/cache
2. Instantiate the client builder:

   ```
   OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
       .cache(cache)
       .addInterceptor(new RewriteRequestInterceptor())
       .addNetworkInterceptor(new RewriteResponseCacheControlInterceptor())
   ```
3. Create the RewriteRequestInterceptor

   ```
   public class RewriteRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {
       @Override
       public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
           int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5;
           Request request;
           if (NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable()) {
               request = chain.request();
           } else {
               request = chain.request().newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "max-stale=" + maxStale).build();
           }
           return chain.proceed(request);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create the RewriteResponseCacheControlInterceptor

   ```
   public class RewriteResponseCacheControlInterceptor implements Interceptor {
       @Override
       public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
           int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5;
           Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
           return originalResponse.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=120, max-stale=" + maxStale).build();
       }
   }
   ```

**It's important to make sure you add the ResponseCacheControlInterceptor as a Network Interceptor, and the RewriteRequestInterceptor as a Interceptor (as I did in the 2nd step).**

Answer (score -4):

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(cache).build();
```

Comment: Please provide some info or explanation for you solution.